# error: missing template arguments before for constexpr member variables

Tags: c++, templates

I have looked at some of the similar questions, and haven't found any solution that works for my use case. I have a constexpr variable that I want to template with default arguments, and I can't seem to get it to work:

```cpp
// Test.hpp
class Test
{
public:
    template <bool val = false>
    constexpr static bool MY_BOOL = val;
};

// Test.cpp
#include "Test.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::MY_BOOL << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

g++ compiler error:

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:6:29: error: missing template arguments before ‘<<’ token
  std::cout << Test::MY_BOOL << "\n";
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong / if this can be fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template argument list following a template name can be omitted only for a function template. For a variable template, class template, or alias template, even if you don't want to provide any explicit arguments, you need at least the empty list `<>`.

To use your default template argument of `false`:

```
std::cout << Test::MY_BOOL<> << "\n";
```